# Transform a delegate to a Expression Tree

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, expression-trees

I wonder if you can create and modify a Expression Tree out of a existing delegate.

Kinda like

```
public void Foo() {
  Console.WriteLine(1000); 
}
....
Expression exp = Foo.GetExpression(); 
//Now do something what changes 1000 to 2000...
```

So I would like to reverse engineer a allready excisting Method.

My problem is that I have a construction like this:

```
var acts = new Action[20];

for (int i = 0; i != 20; i++)        
    acts[i] = () => { Console.WriteLine(i); };
```

and by the way C# works all acts do the same (prints 20). But I want that that

```
acts[5]()
```

print 5

```
acts[11]()
```

prints 11 and so on.

So I need to compute 20 different delegates and I wonder what's a "nice" approach to do so. Of course I could just write:

```
acts[0] = () => Console.WriteLine(0); 
acts[1] = () => Console.WriteLine(1); 
acts[2] = () => Console.WriteLine(2); 
acts[3] = () => Console.WriteLine(3); 
....
```

But that's not a good approach in my eyey...

Answer (score 3):

Anton's solution is *nearly* right, but he's copying the variable at the wrong time. You want this:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 20; i++)
{
    int tmp = i;
    acts[i] = () => Console.WriteLine(tmp);
}
```

This way the *captured variable* is `tmp` rather than `i` - and while there's only one `i` variable, whose value changes on each iteration, you get a "new" `tmp` variable for each iteration.

See Eric Lippert's blog posts on the topic ([part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)) for more details.

(To answer the original question as per the title - you can't create an expression tree from a delegate in a useful way here - the only expression tree you can create is one which just calls the original delegate.)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i != 20; i++)        
{
    var x = i;
    acts[i] = () => { Console.WriteLine(x); };
}
```

Comment: That will have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks both of you! That was what I wanted to know :)